# VBA Excel - Save as .xlsm followed by save as .pdf location issue

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a template worksheet I use to create daily reports. I am trying to create a macro that uses save as to save and rename the template, then export that newly created xlsm  as pdf. Both files need to be saved in the same location. I can get each to work separately but when I try to combine the two into one macro I run into a runtime error.

This works but saves the PDF to desktop

```
    Sub SaveRoutine()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\Time Study\Timelines\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "- Shift 2" & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
    Worksheets("overview").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

This returns a runtime error after saving as xlms.

```
    Sub SaveRoutine()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\Time Study\Timelines\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "- Shift 2" & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

Worksheets("overview").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="U:\Time Study\Timelines\", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I am sure its simple and I have tried variations in the Filename:= variable but can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have a file location, but no file name. You would need some kind of filename`Filename:="s:\dmorrison\testMeNow.pdf"`

Comment: So I should use `Filename:=U:\Time Study\Timelines\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "- Shift 2" & ".pdf"`

Comment: Yes,...btw..you have a quote missing

Comment: thanks. For the ExportAsFixedFormat I thought that if you didn't specify the filename or location it would use the current name and save in current location. I will use your solution but am still curious why it saves to desktop when I don't specify a name.

Comment: I figured out my misunderstanding. when no location or name is specified it uses current file name and *Default* location.

Comment: @VBAndy Actually, if you don't specify a path, it saves it to the **current** directory.  (But the current directory is not the last place you saved a file.)  So, if you included the statements `ChDrive "U": ChDir "\Time Study\Timelines"` prior to saving your pdf file, then the `Filename:=""` would cause the file to be saved in the current directory on the current drive (i.e. `"\Time Study\Timelines"` on the `"U"` drive).  You can use the [`CurDir` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/curdir-function) to see what the current directory is.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks. I originally thought that saving the file first in the desired location as an .xlsm would make that location the **current** directory. I will do some research to find out what factors change the current directory. I have two solutions now but am curious. Might come in handy next time I am bumbling my way through some VBA code.

Comment: One factor that affects the current directory is the use of the [`Application.GetOpenFilename` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getopenfilename-method-excel). (It even includes a warning in the documentation saying "This method may change the current drive or folder.")  So using that to allow the user to select where to save a file and what name to use would change the current directory, which means a subsequent save without a path would also be saved into that same location.